# String value has to be retrieved from html page and stored in xml under categories

Tags: php, html, xml

For a project, I need to pull out the value of a character ('v') from an HTML page generated by me.

The HTML page contains the following links with much garbage data around it:

```
/watch?v=blablabla&list=blablabla&index=7&feature=blablabla
/watch?v=blablabla&list=blablabla&index=8&feature=blablabla
```

The task is the values of 'v' has to be retrieved & stored under categories in an XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions with `preg_match_all`

```
$file = file('path/file.html');
preg_match_all("/\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9]+)&list=[a-z0-9]*&index=[0-9]*/i", $file, $matches);
```

I'm not sure what the URL's will look like, so the regexp will have to be altered for that.

Try http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to fine-tune your expression